# time limit function execution in PHP or anything else

Tags: php, exception, time, limit

I could say that my question is related to PHP, but what I'm more concerned is proper logic of programming in situation where function execution can go on indefinitely.

What is the proper way of monitoring time that it takes to execute some function and how to stop this execution and go on with the rest of the program?

OK, I know that for example there is a set_time_limit() function that returns fatal error but I don't want this, I want my code to just continue after x seconds, or maybe after time exceeded throw an exception, catch it and do something else?

Is writing some kind of a "watchdog" function solution and how is this done?

Thank you for any help that you can provide, any link, any article that addresses this problem in a way that it "should" be done.

BR,
Newman

Comment: What is the context, more specifically?  I'm guessing that the function contains some sort of loop.  If this is correct, my first instinct would be to take a timestamp with `microtime()` before entering the loop and then compare that timestamp with one that is generated inside the loop at each iteration.  Upon reaching a certain value, you could throw an exception, or do anything else.

Perhaps I have misinterpreted the context of what you are trying to do, though.  Are you looking for something you can apply more readily to numerous functions?

Comment: yes,something like that. my problem is that one of my functions is trying to telnet to other device and sometimes telnet timeout is to long.

Answer (score 3):

PHP doesn't provide a general way to timeout a function. But many components where this problem is common let you define a timeout.

Examples:

- The [HTTP Stream Wrapper](http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php) allows you to specify a `timeout` option:

  ```
   file_get_contents('http://example.com', false, stream_context_create(
       array('http' => array('timeout' => 10 /* seconds */))
   ));
  ```
- PDO (database abstraction layer) allows you to set a timeout using the [`PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT` attribute](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php) (note that this attribute may mean different things with different database drivers):

  ```
   $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT, 10 /* seconds */);
  ```
- You can set a connection timeout when using [FTP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-connect.php):

  ```
   $ftp = ftp_connect('example.com', 21, 10 /* seconds */)
  ```

Similarly all other extensions that access potentially remote resources will provide such timeout parameters or options.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP in particular, I don't think you have a valid way to control the execution time for your functions from outside of them.
Like you said, things like `set_time_limit` will throw a Fatar Error and kill your script.

I would suggest messuring your excecution time from within your functions, using things like `microtime()` and throw an exception if the time limit is exeeded; an exception that you'll be able to catch outside and continue act accordingly.

Comment: OK, I will try it like thay. but how is this problem addressed generally (not PHP)?

Comment: I think it depends on the language you're using. Some like Earlang allow the programmer to attach process together allowing them to monitor each other. I don't know if there is a standard technique to handle this scenario, but if there is, please comment letting me know the name :)